# Why not the big crunch?

Tags: big-bang

Entropy 
As per the second law of thermodynamics 
"Order tends to disorder"
And recently I watched a video series by **minute physics**
[3:25
The Big Picture: Entropy & Time (feat. Sean Carroll)S1 • E1
Why Doesn't Time Flow Backwards? (Big Picture Ep. 1/5)
minutephysics
CC](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yKbJ9leUNDE)

As per that with increasing time there will be increasing entropy.
And therefore it is said:-
As time progresses we will be left with just empty space,
Thus based on the above information I would like to ask 
1)thus the big crunch of the ending of the universe cannot take place!
2)how did the big bang infinitely small point come into play! ???

Comment: [The Big Bang did not happen at a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)

Answer (score 0):

The entropic description of fate of universe does not make much sense. The disorder, or unavailability of energy to perform mechanical work is very different phenomena from gravity.

If left alone, gravity does not reduce availability of energy to perform work. On the contrary, it maintains the availability of energy. Examples - 1. Something put into the orbit, gravity maintains the availability of energy. 2. Make a hole through center of a planet, drop something in it. If no resistance, the mechanical energy does not disappear ever.

It is other processes like resistance, friction, impact of falling, energy escaping as radiation... so on that cause the entropy to go up. Gravity by itself does not increase entropy. Gravity can catch up and bring back the entropy to lower levels at universe scale. Therefore big crunch can not be ruled out.